# Harmon.ie custom list not shown in Outlook

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-2013, outlook-2010, harmon.ie

I created a new SharePoint 2013 project in order to customize a doclib witht the columns and views we would like to use to store our emails, using Harmon.ie. After deployment of the wsp on the sharepoint, everything is working fine in terms of SharePoint, but Harmon.ie (installed on Outlook 2010) does not seem to detect the new list based on our library template. When using a standard DocLib or List templates to create a new list, they are showing up fine.
Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried to contact hanrmon.ie developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

harmon.ie offers the option to display Document libraries and Lists by templates ID.
Please read carefully our KB on the subject at: https://harmon.ie/provision-harmonie-outlook-all-users  (registry key: IncludedLibraryTemplates)

---- Jean

Comment: Great! With some searching I was able see them (using the TemplateType from the ListInstance as the List ID in the registry)!